# Feedback on my Company's Logo?

Tags: color, logo, design-principles, text

I just started my first high school graphic design class a couple months ago, and now I'm using Illustrator to make a logo for my software company.

**Info on my company:**

- I develop applications for smart phones, sometimes games, and tools for other developers to use
- I try to give users the power of complexity in a simple way (eg. an iphone has some complex soft and hard-ware behind it, yet it's extremely easy to use).
- I try to look at how nature solves problems, and base my solutions around that.
- I try to look at issues from a broad and narrow perspective as to come up with the best solution

**Here's 3 versions of my current Logo I threw together:**
[image: 3-up]

1. *How can I make my logo more visually attractive / noticeable?*
2. *How can I re-design parts of it to better promote my company's motos and ideas?*

Comment: This is a Q&A forum. A more appropriate place to seek critique of your work or solicit help with a particular piece of design is deviantArt or Behance. The "questions" you've asked are either too spefic to your project to be useful to others, or they're too broad/subjective for a Q&A format.

Comment: If you do a search here on this site related to logos you might find some insight on tips for building better logos. :]

Comment: You should also consider reading up on branding and taking a look at some brand/corporate identity guidelines. There are also some great articles online from professional creative agencies that walk through their process in developing a new brand (including logo design and color and typography choices).

Answer (score 6):

There is too much complexity in your logo. Try to make it more simple and use a maximum of four main colors.

Comment: I agree. too much detail, font is way too small, stars are incredibly tiny. It will look like smears on a business card and can't reproduce to embroidery on a shirt. The third one can't reproduce to B/W or grayscale.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum and spudwaffle: Ok, so what do you think of the very simple first one and how do you suggest I overlay the text?

Comment: Clear the schmutz out of the iris, and the text doesn't belong in the lids. Seriously, shrink the logo to half an inch wide and print it on your desktop laser printer. Unless you can read all your text at that size, it's not going to work.

Comment: Pretty much everything Lauren Ipsum said. The laser printer thing is an excellent idea.

Comment: Can only reinforce what has already been said. Logo is too complicated (even the first one) and the font is too small and unreadable.